# How to restrict unauthorized calls to image resizing service?

Tags: security, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, image-resizing, signature

We have an ***image resizing service*** which resizes images on fly based on query parameters.
Resized images we store into **s3**. Also the service under **cloudfront**.

Is there any idea how to protect service from unauthorized calls ?

We can add a signature to the request url on each call but it is possible to hack as we have to implement signature generating logic in front-end.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but youo can migrate to APIGW+Lambda and use Authorization or x-api-keys etc

Comment: Hey @JamesDean thank you for the answer. 
All the images should be public and question is based on what we can create authorization keys to authorize requests.
For example we can generate authorization key based on url parameters but as we should implement it in front end side anyone can see implementation and hack it.

Comment: WAF is another way but you need to differentiate unauthorized calls and authorized calls.